# Can't import ò character in my Postgres DB - LC_COLLATE not UTF-8

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm having trouble importing data to my postgreSQL database surely because of encoding.
Here's what I have :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [574, "\xf3"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: 7 ERREUR: séquence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage « UTF8 » : 0xf3

Apparently the `ò` character encoded `\xf3` is making this error.

When I create my Postgresql 11.5 database with the command :

`php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

with the following doctrine configuration and adding the 3 last lines

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8
            collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

I still have the same error. And in my pgAdmin interface, i see that my DB is init with the following SQL :

```sql
CREATE DATABASE db
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'French_France.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'French_France.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

Apparently the `LC_COLLATE` and `LC_TYPE` are not well set.

And when I try to create my database from pgAdmin there's no **utf8** proposed in the dropdowns.

And through command line, it creates the database, but it seems it can't find the right encoding, as if the utf8 character type was not installed (sorry all the message errors are in french):

> postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "db" WITH OWNER = "postgres" ENCODING='UTF8' LC_COLLATE ='fr_FR.utf8' LC_CTYPE='fr_FR.utf8' TEMPLATE template0;
>
> ATTENTION:  n'a pas pu déterminer l'encodage pour la locale « fr_FR.utf8 » : le codeset vaut « CPutf8 »
>
> ATTENTION:  n'a pas pu déterminer l'encodage pour la locale « fr_FR.utf8 » : le codeset vaut « CPutf8 »

And I also try to use the `utf8_encode()` **php** method, but it did nothing.

`$entity->setName(utf8_encode($row['name']));`

Does someone as any clue on this ?

Comment: You should set the client encoding to `WIN1253`, `LATIN1` or whatever encoding you are using in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your help @LaurenzAlbe . But as the data I import can be from any languages, I'm scared that just changing the encoding to `LATIN1` for this specific https://www.codetable.net/hex/f3 data, won't solve all my future problems.
Isn't there a way to install the utf-8 character set. Because it's like it is not installed. (I'm not a pro pgsql, so maybe i'm wrong about this thought..)

Comment: The data you have isn't in utf-8 which is why you are getting the error. The database is in utf-8 and can store any characters you want. However, you need to know the character set of the data you are importing - there is no magic way around that because xF3 is different characters in different 8-bit character sets.

Comment: maybe iconv can help. I really wonder though, why utf8_encode doesn't work ...

Comment: @Pilou The encoding need not be different for different languages. If you use UTF8 inside your client application, you can support all languages.

Comment: @RichardHuxton In fact, the data is coming from a MS Access db and is normally utf8 as it is by default.
@Jakumi, it appear I did test with the `utf8_encode()` method on the wrong `$row['name'])` attribute... and doing the test on the right one (few lines upper) finally did the trick for me. I'm a bit sorry about all the time spent on this subject for me and for you. But actually the question is resolved.
Even if I would have liked to learn more about encoding, as I don't know much..
Thank you very much all